# Imacros with many conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, imacros

how to create a script with imacros with many conditions?
for example:

1. if it can click, will continue
2. if it can not click, will return to the specified url

Tried so far:

```
SET !VAR1 "POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN"
SET !VAR2 "URL GOTO=url"
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var d=\"{{TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN}}\";
var s=\"{{URL GOTO=url}}\" ;
if ((d!=s)){
  var x = \"TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN\";
} else {
  var x=\"URL GOTO=url\";
} x;")
```

Comment: Can you show us code examples of what you tried? We cannot write your code for you.

Comment: SET !VAR1 "POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN"

SET !VAR2 "URL GOTO=url"

SET !VAR3 EVAL("var d=\"{{TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN}}\"; var s=\"{{URL GOTO=url}}\" ; if ((d!=s)){var x = \"TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN\";} else {var x=\"URL GOTO=url\";} x;")

Comment: is there any error from that script?
I keep the execution path without conditions

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your question and paste your code in there?

Comment: how to create a script with imacros with many conditions?
for example: a. if it can click, will continue b. if it can not click, will return to the specified url

Comment: this script :

SET !VAR1 "POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN"

SET !VAR2 "URL GOTO=url"

SET !VAR3 EVAL("var d=\"{{TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN}}\"; var s=\"{{URL GOTO=url}}\" ; if ((d!=s)){var x = \"TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:LANJUTKAN<SP>KE<SP>PEMBAYARAN\";} else {var x=\"URL GOTO=url\";} x;")